# Dialog does not open when in mobile version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have this dialog for logging out the user. When the screen is large, it works fine, however, if it is in a smaller screen size. The dialog will not pop up.

Using this inside the `navBar`:

```
{/* Mobile Menu Dialog */}
        <Dialog as="div" className="lg:hidden" open={mobileMenuOpen} onClose={() => setMobileMenuOpen(false)}>
              <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50" />
              <Dialog.Panel className="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 z-50 w-full overflow-y-auto bg-white px-6 py-6 sm:max-w-sm sm:ring-1 sm:ring-gray-900/10">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                  <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                    <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
                    <img
                      className="h-8 w-auto"
                      src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </a>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="-m-2.5 rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                    onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(false)}
                  >
                    <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                    <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-6 flow-root">
                  <div className="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-500/10">
                    <div className="space-y-2 py-6">
                      {navigationItems.map((item) => (
                        <a
                          key={item.name}
                          href={item.href}
                          className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </a>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                    <LogoutButton session={session} isMobile={mobileMenuOpen}/>
                    Logout
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Dialog.Panel>
            </Dialog>
```

The button to logout:

```
interface LogoutButtonProps {
  session: boolean;
  isMobile: boolean;
}

const LogoutButton: React.FC<LogoutButtonProps> = ({ session, isMobile }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleOpen = () => setIsOpen(true);
  const toggleClose = () => setIsOpen(false);

  console.log(isMobile, toggleOpen, "tried")

  return (
    <div className={isMobile ? 'flex justify-start pt-5' : 'hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end'}>
      {session ? (
        <>
          <Button onClick={toggleOpen}>Logout</Button>
          <div className={'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0'}>
            <DialogComponent isOpen={isOpen} onClose={toggleClose}>
              <h3 className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900" id="modal-title">
                Are you sure you want to log out?
              </h3>

              <div className="px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse justify-start sm:px-6 gap-4">
                <div>
                  <form action="/auth/signout" method="post">
                    <Button type="submit" variant="destructive">
                      Sign out
                    </Button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Button type="button" variant="secondary" onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </DialogComponent>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <a href="/login" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
          {isMobile ? 'Log in' : 'Log in'} <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LogoutButton;
```

The output for these:   `console.log(isMobile, toggleOpen, "tried")`

```
true ()=>setIsOpen(true) tried
```